# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createComponentInstance' of 'Vue.ssrUtils' as it is undefined for nuxt and jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, frontend, nuxt.js

I am trying to onboard the jest testing framework to my nuxt project but while doing this,

I got a major roadblock as I am not able to test the simple component. I am not able to find any proper solution related to this question, if anyone faced the same issue can you please help here.

**The test spec file I wrote is:**

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import test from '../pages/test.vue'
describe('test', () => {
test('is a Vue instance', () => {
const wrapper = mount(test)
expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
})
})
```

**Below is my package.json**

```
{
 "name": "test",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "test",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "dev": "nuxt",
 "build": "nuxt build",
 "start": "nuxt start",
 "test": "jest -u - runInBand - coverage - passWithNoTests",
 
 "config": {
 "nuxt": {
 "host": "0.0.0.0"
 }
 },
}
```

**my jest config:**

```
module.exports={
 moduleNameMapper: {
 '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components',
 '^~/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/pages',
 '^vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
 
 },
 moduleFileExtensions: [
 'js',
 'vue',
 'json'
 ],
 transform: {
 '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest',
 "^.+\.js$": "babel-jest",
 ".*\.(vue)$": 'vue-jest',
 '.*\\.(vue)$': 'vue-jest',
 
 },
 testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
 //testResultsProcessor: "jest-sonar-reporter",
 collectCoverage: true,
 collectCoverageFrom: [
 '<rootDir>/components/**/*.vue',
 '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.vue',
 '<rootDir>/pages/**/*.js',
 
 ],
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw that [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/3379) is closed on GitHub. May it will be useful

Comment: Thanks for answer but I don't have any webpack configuration in my project, I do have nuxt.config.js when I try to add in the nuxt.config and run.. it is not working.. I am wondering how jest file will refer my nuxt.config.js file while running test command

Answer (score 0):

1. Downgrade `@vue/test-utils` to `1.3.0` for error `Cannot destructure property 'createComponentInstance' of 'Vue.ssrUtils'`
2. `npm install jest-environment-jsdom --save-dev` for error
   `window is undefined, vue-test-utils needs to be run in a browser environment.`
3. Add this line to jest config
   `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` or `testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom"` like you did and add file `.babelrc`

```json
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "targets": {
              "node": "current"
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```